# Automatic IP addressing in Ethernet network is not working

Tags: ip, ethernet, omnet++

I am new to OMNET++ (version 5.4) simulator and i have been trying to do some tutorials to learn it. Now I am working on doing an example Ethernet connections as in the picture.[image]

and I have the following configuration in my ´net.ini´ file

```
[General]
# Configurator settings
*.net_configurator.dumpAddresses = true
*.net_configurator.dumpTopology = true
*.net_configurator.dumpLinks = true
*.net_configurator.dumpRoutes = true

# Routing settings
**.networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = ""
*.*.networkLayer.arpType = "GlobalARP"
*.*.routingTable.netmaskRoutes = ""


# Visualizer settings
*.visualizer.interfaceTableVisualizer.displayInterfaceTables = true
*.visualizer.interfaceTableVisualizer.nodeFilter = "not (*switch* or *Switch*  or *AP*)"

[Config Step1]
network = net
description = "Fully automatic IP address assignment"
```

when I lunch the simulation i don't see any IP assigning . what could be the problem?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the line:

```
**.networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = ""
```

into:

```
**.networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = "net_configurator"
```

---

Other way is to do:

1. Change the name of `IPv4NetworkConfigurator` object to `configurator`.
2. Remove the line:

   ```
   **.networkLayer.configurator.networkConfiguratorModule = ""
   ```